# Using Event.target and class to close an off-screen nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a little help understanding the event.target property.

I've created a `nav` that slides in and out when a `button` is clicked.  When the `nav` is on-screen, it has the class `nav-open` added to it. I was attempting to add the functionality that if the user click *anywhere but the `nav`* it would close, so I attempted to target:

1. the class name
2. the users click

with the following code but it does not seem to be working:

```
    $(window).click(function(e) {
        if( nav.hasClass('nav-open') && e.target != nav ) {
            nav.removeClass('nav-open');
        }

    });
```

Can anyone help? Full snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var button = $('button');
 var nav = $('nav');
 
 button.click(function() {
  nav.toggleClass('nav-open');
 });
 
//  $(window).click(function(e) {
//   if( nav.hasClass('nav-open') && e.target != nav ) {
//    nav.removeClass('nav-open');
//   }
  
//  });
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
 border: 1px solid;
 height: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

button{
 position: relative;
 left: 500px;
 top: 30px;
}

nav {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 300px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #444;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
.nav-open {
 transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
 <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var button = $('button');
 var nav = $('nav');
 
 button.click(function() {
  nav.toggleClass('nav-open');
 });
 
  $("body").on("click", ".container", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("nav").hasClass("nav-open")){
      $("nav").removeClass("nav-open");
    }
  }).on("click", "nav, button", function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
 border: 1px solid;
 height: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

button{
 position: relative;
 left: 500px;
 top: 30px;
}

nav {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 300px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #444;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
.nav-open {
 transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
 <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you  please explain your example?

Comment: You need to pass in the event for `on( 'click', 'nav', function () {} )`.

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Sure. You need to add an event for `body` and close the navigation. If `nav` is clicked you add `stopPropagation`  to prevent the event from bubbling up, so it does not take the event from parent.

Comment: @Kushtrim so the first e.preventDefault() does what?  I get that the .click, nav function stops the event from bubbling up, but what about that first part

Comment: I just added `e.preventDefault()` in case you had any links in the page and that would redirect somewhere else. You can remove it.

Comment: Oh that makes sense!